# Price of Blackmarket Substances

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, pricing, medicine-and-drugs

I have a player (ruthless drug lord) who is attempting to buy an injected incapacitating agent called [sodium thiopental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_thiopental). Since thiopental cannot be bought on the open market, I'm having trouble figuring out how much it should cost. This is just one example of blackmarket things my players want. Can someone help me find out a universally applicable technique to discern the black market price of items?

Comment: Does your campaign mainly track dollars and cents or favors and reputation?

Comment: Dollars. Our drug lord in question has a $9000 budget.

Comment: As a general note, you might want to wait at least 24 hours before making an answer as accepted. This way, you may get a higher amount of, potentially, good answers that would have expanded on this - closing early dissuades people to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One of the ways could be to simply go to I2P or TOR and find the info - I personally didn't check, but am 100% sure that someone will be willing to sell it. Though keep in mind that it may attract unneeded real-life attention to you, and you may have a hard time answering to FBI that you didn't really plan to buy it. After all, you are not really planning to buy it, don't you? ***So don't do it, really.***
- The other way would be to figure out the way your target drug is manufactured and calculate the approximate costs. Think of the risks -- how hard is it to hide manufacturing itself, buying the precursors or, in turn, manufacturing them too, etc. May be a hard way, but still...
- Since this drug is still actively used, as I understand it from Wikipedia, you may try to google for the price. [This site](http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/thiopental/thipen.htm), for example, gives some info about it, with the price in indian rupies (38 rupies as of 08.08.2017, or 60 US cents). Also keep in mind that when US switched from that drug to some other, the costs of one lethal injection increased from ~87 dollars to ~1250 dollars, and they used enormous dosage to kill, far greater than dosage needed for medical purposes, so its cost can be assumed to be insignificant.

  When you know the legal price (or the costs), you can try to compare it to other black market entities and raise the price to approximately that level. For example, heroine is very expensive in black market even though the costs of production are very low.
- Probably, it would be wise for your character to simply try to steal it, given the supernatural abilities of vampires? If your chronicle takes place in a country that manufactures the thing or uses it, that's a way I would allow in my chronicle. Or maybe it would be more wise for your PC to pay to someone who will steal it for him, like some Nosferatu neonate who would most likely have no problems doing so and probably needs some starting cash (or a favor... it's Camarilla, by the way, isn't it?).
- If the drug or other thing is not manufactured at all anymore, the price is likely to be ridiculously high if you try to buy it, or ridiculosly low if your druglord owns a laboratory that may manufacture it himself. It is not unlikely, isn't it?

Hope that it helps.

Comment: Perfect! All of these suggestions were very helpful.

Comment: TOR is a technical method (a routing service) to avoid Discovery of your identity, it is not a criminal network. Many normal people use TOR for normal stuff too. It's the same for l2p, although l2p is more of an actual service. It's not 'the darknet' you can buy illegal stiff with, it's social networks that use these technologies to stay anonymous.

Comment: @DoomedMind Aye, however, the reputation of both is a bit dirty not without reasons.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Yeah, that's true. I just wanted to point out the difference between networking tools and actual networks for readers not as knowledgeable with these technologies.

Comment: Googling information on a price is not a crime and you don't have to answer FBI anything. And you especially won't have a hard time. In a very unlikely case FBI will actually ask you, the answer is very easy: "I was doing research for my game". That is of course if the OP is even living in the United States. There are many countries where FBI has no authority, you know. On the other hand, If OP lives in some North Korea, you may be right, it is dangerous to do research.